# Dystopian book in which kids compete for a spot in a space mission

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this book (I think it became a trilogy) years and years ago. The world is ending and two kids were picked by the government, along with others, to compete for a spot in a space mission. The girl goes to space and the boy is left behind. I think the cover had a sunset on it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when "years and years ago" was?  Do you remember where the space mission was headed?

Answer (score 11):

Found it. It's *[The Final Six](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36491465-the-final-six)* by Alexandra Monir.

> When Leo, an Italian championship swimmer, and Naomi, a science genius from California, are two of the twenty-four teens drafted into the International Space Training Camp, their lives are forever altered. After erratic climate change has made Earth a dangerous place to live, the fate of the population rests on the shoulders of the final six who will be scouting a new planet. Intense training, global scrutiny, and cutthroat opponents are only a few of the hurdles the contestants must endure in this competition.
>
> For Leo, the prospect of traveling to Europa—Jupiter’s moon—to help resettle humankind is just the sense of purpose he’s been yearning for since losing his entire family in the flooding of Rome. Naomi, after learning of a similar space mission that mysteriously failed, suspects the ISTC isn’t being up front with them about what’s at risk.
>
> As the race to the final six advances, the tests get more challenging—even deadly. With pressure mounting, Naomi finds an unexpected friend in Leo, and the two grow closer with each mind-boggling experience they encounter. But it’s only when the finalists become fewer and their destinies grow nearer that the two can fathom the full weight of everything at stake: the world, the stars, and their lives.

Comment: It's great you figured it out.  Can you tell us a bit more about it, like who wrote it and when?

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find [tips on how to write a good story identification answer and what details to add in our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7957).